# Python Unit-Testing: Nose @with_setup failing

Tags: python, unit-testing, decorator, nose

I'm doing some tests. A bunch of my test functions have common setups, so I decided I should use `@with_setup` decorator from `nose.tools`. I've simplified my problem down to this:

```
from nose.tools import with_setup

class TestFooClass(unittest.TestCase):
   def setup_foo_value(self):
      self.foo = 'foobar'

   @with_setup(setup_foo_value)
   def test_something(self):
      print self.foo
```

I get the following error:

```
$ python manage.py test tests/test_baz.py

E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_something (project.tests.test_baz.TestFooClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Coding/project-backend/project/../project/tests/test_baz.py", line 17, in test_something
    print self.foo
AttributeError: 'TestFooClass' object has no attribute 'foo'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's like `setup_foo_value` is not being run at all. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Do you know that you can define `setUp()` in your `unittest.TestCase` subclass to do this?

Answer (score 14):

According to the doc:

- [writing tests](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html): "Please note that method generators *are not* supported in `unittest.TestCase` subclasses"
- [testing tools](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.with_setup): "`with_setup` is useful *only* for test functions, not for test methods or inside of TestCase subclasses"

So you can either move your test method into a function, or add a [`setUp`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) method to your class.

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this modification. It worked for me.

```
from nose.tools import with_setup

def setup_foo_value(self):
    self.foo = 'foobar'

@with_setup(setup_foo_value)
def test_something(self):
    print self.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial idea can be implemented in the following way

```
import wrapt

@wrapt.decorator
def setup_foo_value(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
   instance.foo = 'foobar'
   return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

class TestFooClass(unittest.TestCase):
   @setup_foo_value
   def test_something(self):
      print self.foo
```

**Important** that It additionally uses [wrapt](http://www.slideshare.net/GrahamDumpleton/pycon-nz-2013-advanced-methods-for-creating-decorators) *Python* module